# Why does "Into the unknown" have 2 versions?

Tags: soundtrack, frozen-2

In Frozen 2 Elsa sings

> Every day's a little harder as I feel MY power grow

While Panic! At the Disco (while closing credits is on) sings

> Every day's a little harder as I feel YOUR power grow

Why? 
My thoughts is that it's Elsa's song, so she sings about herself while Brendon Urie sings to her... But maybe there's another reason?

Comment: Same happened to "Let it go". The lyrics of the original and the one sung By Demi Lovato in the credits are different. I don't think there is a specific reason, though. Making multiple versions of a song is pretty common in the industry.

Comment: To continue @BellaSwan thought, especially Disney films. The Lion King & Mulan come to mind. Maybe it's a way to get on the pop charts?

Comment: Well, maybe it is... To be honest, I wan't able  to watch them in original when I was a child so I even didn't know, and I'm happy that I asked it now, so I find this out... But in case with frozen they really just swap my with your %) Like they are must sing together, Shi sings about herself and he sings to her :3